Network Transfer Speed Discrepancy between Servers Using SCP / Rsync
I'm experiencing significantly slower SCP transfer speeds between two of my servers, despite both having the same bandwidth capacities. Here are the details of the setup:
Source Server X (Slow)
IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Average Transfer Speed: ~400kB/s

Source Server Y (Fast)
IP: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
Average Transfer Speed: ~80MB/s

Destination Server Z
IP: zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz

Protocol: SCP (Secure Copy Protocol)
Nature of Files: Compressed files ranging from a few MBs to tens of GBs. Generally, transferring one file at a time.
MTR Results from Source Server X to Destination Server Z (1000 packets):
$ mtr -rw -c 1000 zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
Start: 2024-07-15T09:47:56+0200
HOST: SourceServer1   Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst  StDev
1.|-- hop1              1.4%  1000   0.8   0.5   0.4  24.6   0.9
2.|-- hop2              1.0%  1000   1.0   2.8   0.6 150.0  12.2
3.|-- hop3              0.9%  1000   1.6   5.6   0.7 193.2  21.5
4.|-- hop4              0.8%  1000   7.9   8.9   7.2 119.5   9.4
5.|-- hop5              1.2%  1000   7.4   7.4   7.0  25.0   1.6
6.|-- ???              100.0  1000   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
7.|-- ???              100.0  1000   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
8.|-- hop8              1.1%  1000   7.4   7.1   6.8  30.9   1.0
9.|-- hop9              1.9%  1000  12.9  15.2  12.5  89.5  10.7
10.|-- ???             100.0  1000   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
11.|-- hop11           66.0%  1000  19.7  20.1  17.0  72.1   7.2
12.|-- ???             100.0  1000   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
13.|-- ???             100.0  1000   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
14.|-- ???             100.0  1000   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
15.|-- ???             100.0  1000   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
16.|-- destination      1.0%  1000  16.6  16.3  16.2  25.4   0.6

Rsync Results from Source Server X to Destination:
example.zip
402,100,224  100%  414.11kB/s  0:15:48  (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
sent 325,885,177 bytes  received 35 bytes  340,705.92 bytes/sec
total size is 402,100,224  speedup is 1.23

Rsync Results from Source Server Y to Destination:
example.zip
402,100,224  100%  43.51MB/s  0:00:08  (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
sent 98 bytes  received 140,442 bytes  11,243.20 bytes/sec
total size is 402,100,224  speedup is 2,861.11

Steps Taken So Far:

Verified resource usage (CPU, RAM, I/O) on Source Server X – no issues found.
Disabled firewall temporarily to rule out any    restrictions.
Contacted the provider, who says no internal issues and suggested external network issues instead.
Tried to send the same file from other four source servers to Server Z using rsync, always obtaining a 10 seconds max transfer.

The issue persists across different times and destinations.
Similar speed tests (speedtest-cli) show inconsistent results, with Source Server X always being significantly slower.
What could be causing the significantly slower SCP transfer speeds on Source Server X compared to Source Server Y, despite having the same bandwidth capacities and no apparent resource bottlenecks? How can I further diagnose and resolve this issue? MTR suggests a bottleneck on hop11 (fra1-lim1-g1-8k.de.eu) but I'm not sure how to overcome this.
